# Logic Error Assigning and Printing Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, logic

```
void opt3()
{
    cout << "ENTER STUDENT NAME>";
    cin >> Assigned[Col][Row];//Get New Assignment of Student Name at appropriate Col and Row
    Col++;
    cout << "ENTER COURSE ID>";
    cin >> Assigned[Col][Row];//Get new Assignement of class at appropriate Col and Row
    Row++;
    return;
}
void opt7(int& Col, int& Row)
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    int x,y,z;
    string CouC;
    cout << "ENTER COURSE ID>";
    getline(cin,CouC,'\n');
    bool Ans;
    do
    {
            for (int i=0;i<Row;i++)
            {
                    for (int j=0;j<Col;j++)
                    {
                            x = j;
                            y = i;
                            Ans = CouC.compare(Assigned[j][i]);
                            if(Ans)
                                    z=j;
                    //Compares until it finds the right course ID woop and then sets it to arr$
                    }
            }

    }while (Ans == false);

    for (y=0;y<10;y++)
    {
            cout << Assigned[z][y];//Print out the students in the course
    }
```

This is what my problem section of code looks like. I am having difficulty storing the students in the desired class and then printing them out based on the chosen class. I am trying to compare my array Assigned[][] to the appropriate user input and I can`t seem to figure it out. I currently have no compile errors only logic errors. My output when this is run looks weird. It usually prints a random student name with the course name entered.

Help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: *I am having difficulty storing the students in the desired class*  -- You should write this part of the code first, and test it.  You're asking about 3 separate issues, and we don't know if the one italicized is working properly.  Also, a [mcve] should be posted.

Comment: Also, your assignment is confusing, or you've written some very confusing code.  What is the purpose of the 2d array?  What is "Row" and "Col" supposed to denote?  I would expect a 1 dimensional array, where each element would be student information (as a class or struct), not a 2d array like a chess board.

Comment: Yeah I`m confused myself. I am unable to tackle the problem efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the meaning of the two-dimensional array `Assigned` needs to be defined clearly.

- It could be a boolean matrix of students and courses, where the value would indicate if a student is taking a course, or
- It could be a list of student and course pairs.

The function `opt3()` that fills `Assigned` does something weird: it takes a student and a course, and creates a new column for the student and a new row for the course. So this function seems to use `Assigned` as a matrix, but it adds both a new student and a new course at the same time. Also the values of this matrix are a mix of student and course IDs, and it has many unused values. This does not make much sense.

If the purpose of the function is to input which student takes which course, it should, depending on the meaning of `Assigned`, either

- search for the student column and course row, and set the value to `true`, or
- add a new student and course pair to the list.